# Button placed over a LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to place a Button over the end of my LinearLayout and make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/850eg.png)

So I created a layout and assigned the gradient backgrounds to achieve that look but I found a hard time placing the button on the border of the LinearLayout `fragment_edit_profile.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_toolbar_gradient"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_profile">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Email -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Save Changes"
            android:background="@drawable/button_dark_filled"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Do you guys have any idea how can I achieve this? I searched but didn't find anything useful.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I achieved it:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name_entry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/last_name_entry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email_title"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_entry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Save Changes"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

     </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain to me what did you do here, I found it difficult to try your code

Comment: Sure! Since frame_layout is the parent of the button and the edit_text_linear_layout, they can overlap. It may be easier to see if you change my background colors with resources from your own colors.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to FrameLayout or RelativeLayout outside the LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_toolbar_gradient"
android:padding="20dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_profile"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/input_form"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/input_form"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Email -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Save Changes"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_form"
            android:background="@drawable/button_dark_filled"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your respons. When I add more views (more linearLayouts with an TextView and EditText) I lose the inner background

Comment: Are the views added in LinearLayout with id **input_form**?

Comment: Show me the new XML file.

Comment: Just copy paste a few LinaerLayouts with TextView and EditText and you will see